# Retrieving Data From Firebase Not Displaying Correctly in Console

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm able to display the correct data from my Firebase child in the console with the following code:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('requests');
ref.on('value', gotData, errData);


function gotData(data) {
  var scores = data.val();
  console.log(scores);

}
```

Which displays the following in the console:

[image]

[image]

So when I try to use this snippet of code to retrieve the email:

```
function gotData(data) {
  var scores = data.val();
  console.log(scores);
  var keys = Object.keys(Email);
  console.log(keys);
  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    var k = keys[i];
    var emails = email[k].email;
    console.log(emails);
  }
}
```

it's displaying the following error:

[image]

but I'm not fully understanding why I'm getting this error when this is very similar to other peoples solution.

Anyone know why I'm getting this error when there is an actual value for the email key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the `email` simply to do this:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('requests');
ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
var datas = child.val();
var email=child.val().Email;

  });
});
```

Assuming you have this database:

```
requests
   randomid 
       Email: email_here
```

You need to be iterating inside the randomid to be able to access the property `Email`

Comment: That worked! Thanks. I forgot you had to iterate through it.